# Misaligned form group with the rest of components in Bootstrap CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal form with buttons and text input in HTML, using bootstrap 3

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal form" >
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-12" >

<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="username" >User Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"  name="username" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-1" >
    <div class="form-group" >
        <button class="btn-warning btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" >Add User</button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

If i place the buttons inside a form-group, the buttons are not aligned with other components, because of this:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

(you can see it in full screen)

How can I fix this? Do i need to create a custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at bootstraps examples of forms: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms it only wraps `label` and `input` style elements together in `form-group`

So either remove the wrapper from your `button` and you should be fine.

**ie**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal form" >
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-12" >

<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="username" >User Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"  name="username" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-offset-1" >
    <button class="btn-warning btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" >Add User</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/GdUqrTBoPv)**

---

Alternatively, switch the `form-group` to be the wrapper of `col-md-offset-1` rather than the other way around and give your `col-md-offset-1` a class of `col-md-11`

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal form" >
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-12" >

<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="username" >User Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"  name="username" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11" >
        <button class="btn-warning btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" >Add User</button>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/4jyS34RGM8)**

Comment: the first example works only if this is the last "form group". If you have two rows of buttons, they will be together (form group also have a bottom padding)

Comment: second example is what i need. I tried it, but i included only the col-offset. Using the size and the offset class will solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add form tag

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal form" >
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" >
<div class="col-md-12" >
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group" >
    <label class="col-md-1 control-label" for="username" >User Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-6" >
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="username"  name="username" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn-warning btn" type="button" id="add" name="add" >Add User</button>

</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: nesting `form` elements is a big no-no IMO

Comment: what is problem with form element ?@haxxxton

Comment: there is already a `form` element surrounding all the elements, using its purely for its CSS styling is not its intention, and will almost certainly cause problems with submission of data

Comment: the example does not work, the button is not aligned with the input box, in firefox